# Is "be" verb unnecessary?

Tags: verbs, verb-usage

Is the below sentence correct? I feel ***be*** (is) verb is missing.

> Why this moralising conclusion?

Comment: Where do you think *be* could go in that sentence?

Comment: @nnnnnn So are you saying that quoted sentence is correct?

Comment: Yes. I think it is fine as is, but also I don't know how to change it to include *be* in a way that makes sense. You said you think it is missing, but where would it go?

Comment: Can I change this to "Why is this moralising conclusion?" Does its meaning change?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense like that. You could possibly say "Why is the conclusion moralising like this?" or something like that, but it works much better the original way.

Comment: @nnnnnn Is "moralising" adjective or verb?

Comment: @ARYF it may help to think of 'Why' in this context as an alternative to "What is the reason for...". While this may only confuse things further there is an anachronistic dialect usage in British English where *be* would be used "Why be this moralizing conclusion?" The only time you'd hear it today though would be on international talk like a pirate day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common informal saying in spoken English with the same structure:

> Why the long face?

Which is something you would ask someone who doesn't seem to feel so well. This is a way to say *"What's the matter?" "What's wrong?".* This funny discussion on the BBC website should enlighten you about that one: [BBC.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/theenglishwespeak/2012/05/120522_tews_72_long_face.shtml).

In a spoken discussion with friends or acquaintances, you could use such a structure. You could also say:

> What's with this moralising conclusion?

[Dictionary.com - What's with](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/what-s-with).

In a more formal discussion, you'd prefer using a full appropriate question:

> Why would you end on this moralising conclusion?

Or something along these lines.

Comment: Can I change this to "Why is this moralising conclusion?"

Comment: @ARYF - No, because English sentence structure doesn't work that way.  When you ask about the existence of X, you can't say "Why is X?"  You would have to say, "Why is there X?" or "Why does X exist?"  Also, as MadWard points out, this is an idiomatic construction that doesn't use a verb; it's just "Why *<noun-phrase>*?"

Comment: But you could say "Why is this *a* moralizing conclusion?"

Comment: @user3169: Not really the same meaning.